# Can't configure wsl command line for PyCharm terminal by default

Tags: terminal, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After reinstalling Windows, I try to configure PyCharm with wsl2. But I can’t set it in the settings so that the terminal opens the wsl command line by default. Neither for the global, nor for the project. I tried it as an administrator and still the terminal opens in Powershell.

I tried to write briefly wsl.exe (that’s how it worked for me on my old Windows)
I tried to specify the path C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe. True, for some reason the search doesn’t look for it, but if I do: “dir C:\Windows\system32 -Force”, then I can find this path in a long list. And I can push it in the selection menu, that is, Paycharm seems to see it.
I tried to enter the path "C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wsl.exe" and nothing worked either.

If I try to push through the selection menu, it’s not clear where to point, and by the way, wsl is visible there (//wsl/Ubunta).

[image]

Perhaps the problem is in the paths, like wsl is not registered in the Windows paths, but how can I add it there? What variable should I create for this? And in general, maybe the reason is something else?
I also tried this option, but it doesn’t work either
[image]

And perhaps the reason is that I need to register the starting directory (underlined on the screenshot), but I don’t know what to put there and whether it’s necessary.